# What is the need for MaxAlign trick when creating static singleton?

Tags: c++, singleton, placement-new, c++-loki

Following a snippet of code from [Loki singleton implementation](https://sourceforge.net/p/loki-lib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/include/loki/Singleton.h) which shows what it calls "MaxAlign Trick". I assume it has something to do with alignment (duh!), but what's the purpose of trying to align with all the types mentioned inside the union? Will the placement new inside `Create()` break without it?

```
    template <class T> struct CreateStatic
    {
        union MaxAlign
        {
            char t_[sizeof(T)];
            short int shortInt_;
            int int_;
            long int longInt_;
            float float_;
            double double_;
            long double longDouble_;
            struct Test;
            int Test::* pMember_;
            int (Test::*pMemberFn_)(int);
        };

        static T* Create()
        {
            static MaxAlign staticMemory_;
            return new(&staticMemory_) T;
        }
        
        // other code...

  }
```

Comment: For reference the library doesn't seem to be maintained for the last 9 years or more and this particular piece of code was added [20 years ago](https://sourceforge.net/p/loki-lib/code/31/#diff-11) so may not be the best place to look for modern coding practice. I don't know how this code is supposed to be used but multiple calls to `Create` would appear to construct multiple objects in the same location leading to undefined behaviour

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, you are right. I am just curious, that's all. I believe the `Create` method is guarded by checks when used to prevent overwriting constructions.

Answer (score 0):

`MaxAlign` serves two purposes. First, it is an implementation of the C++11 `std::max_align_t`: "a trivial standard-layout type whose alignment requirement is at least as strict (as large) as that of every scalar type." ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/max_align_t)). Since the alignment of a type is the alignment of the data member with the highest alignment requirements, the definition of `MaxAlign` gives us exactly that: a type that is guaranteed to have the max. alignment for the platform of interest.

Second, it is also a buffer that is large enough to contain a `T`:

```
char t_[sizeof(T)];
```

Taking both aspects, `MaxAlign` provides the C++11 feature `std::aligned_storage_t<size, alignment>` (without taking over-alignment of `T` is into account - it probably didn't even exist back then).

But why is it needed: placement `new` requires the buffer to be suitably aligned for the instance that is being constructed. Without this "alignment trick", you might end up with undefined behaviour. `T` being an unkonwn type, Loki circumvents any risks by choosing the maximal alignment for the platform the code is being compiled for.

In modern code, you would probably not use placement new, but use a `static` object on the stack, e.g.

```
static T& Create() {
    static T instance;
    return instance;
}
```

But 20 years ago, this might not have worked properly across compilers and/or in multi-threaded environments (proper initialisation of `T instance` in the above is only guaranteed since C++11 IIRC).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Won't `static T instance` already meet the alignment requirement for the type `T`, and then we can give it's address to `placement new`? Does `placement new` has its own special requirement?

Comment: Yes, `static T instance` meets the alignment requirement. But as noted at the bottom of the answer, there will be a reason this wasn't implemented with a `static T instance` (which wouldn't need a placement `new` afterwards, since it already invokes a constructor).

Comment: Gotcha. I am still a little bit unsure about the need of all those data type inside the union. Wouldn't just `union MaxAlign{char t_[sizeof(T)];}` or `union MaxAlign{T t_;}` work perfectly just as well? It gives the alignment for type `T`. Appreciate your help.

Comment: `union MaxAlign{char t_[sizeof(T)];}` gives you an alignment of `char` so that wouldn't work. `union MaxAlign{T t_;}` gives you the alignment of `T`, but when you instantiate that on the stack, you end up with the same pattern as `static T instance`, which apparently didn't work back then.

Comment: Okay, so the root cause is issue with alignment of `static` objects pre-C++11 era. This necessitates manually aligning it. Thank you for your patience and help!